# How are "write-anywhere file systems" useful, and how are they implemented?

Tags: filesystems

Basically, I was wondering how write-anywhere file systems provide any advantage over the other kinds of filesystems out there, and how the write-anywhere model manages to do this (in a broad sense)?

Thanks

Comment: What's a write-anywhere file system? One that allows you to write your file all over the MBR? :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are three popular file systems out there that follow in a very board sense the write-anywhere file system approach: The original WAFL used by NetApp ([old technical report](http://media.netapp.com/documents/wp_3002.pdf)), ZFS, BTRFS.

The key properties of these file systems are

1. that there are no pre-assigned parts of the underlying block storage for data and meta data (hence the write-anywhere) and
2. that data is never overwritten, but redirected to a different location on the block storage. The latter property is shared with Flash Transition Layers or special Flash file systems, but usually they don't have property 1.

They have a few nice advantages (as a short summary):

- It is easier and more straightforward to implement advantages file system features like snapshots, CDP, data deduplication.
- Consistency is easier. Recovery after a crash is faster. In theory, a file system check should never be necessary.
- RAID writes can be optimized. Multiple unrelated writes can be placed in a single RAID group, so that the IOs needed for the writes is reduced.